# If $y=f(x)$ be the equation of the parabola which is touched by the line $y=x$

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry

If $y=f(x)$ be the equation of the parabola which is touched by the line $y=x$ at the point where $x=1$.Prove that $f'(1)=1$ and $2f(0)=1-f'(0)$

---

Let $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ be the parabola.Since the parabola is touched by the line $y=x$ at $x=1$.So $f'(1)=1$,because slope of $y=x$ is $1$.
But i cannot prove the second part of the question.

Comment: Are you sure the second relation is not $\;2f'(0)=1-f(0)$?

Comment: Yes,the second is given in the same way in my book as i have written here

Comment: Since "the parabola is touched by the line y= x at x= 1" you have **both** f'(1)= 2a+ b= 1 and f(1)= a+ b+ c= 1.  Subtracting the second from the first, a- c= 0 or a= c. Also, b= 1- 2a.  So we have the parabola f(x)= ax^2+ (1- 2a)x+ a.  Then f(0)= a and f'(0)= 1- 2a= 1- 2f(0). And then 2f(0)= 1- f'(0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the point of intersection as $(1,1)$ . From here $1=a+b+c $ also $\frac {dy }{dx}=1$ thus $1=2a+b $ thus $a=\frac {1-b}{2}$ putting this in earlier equation. We have $1=\frac {1-b}{2}+b+c $ thus $2=1+b+2c $ hence $2c=1-b $ now $2f (0)=2c,1-f'(0)=1-b $. Hence the proof.

Answer (score 1):

The tangent at $x=1$ is given by
$$ y-f(1) = f'(1)(x-1), $$
so for it to be $y=x$, $f'(1)=1$ and $f(1)=1$. This gives us two equations for the coefficients:
\begin{align}
 f(1) = a+b+c = 1 \tag{1} \\
f'(1) = 2a+b = 1. \tag{2}
\end{align}
Meanwhile,
$$ f(0) = c, \\
f'(0) = b. $$
$2(1)-(2)$ gives
$$ b+2c=1 \implies f'(0) + 2f(0) = 1, $$
as required.